# Again... method security with spring boot/security: Error creating bean with name 'methodSecurityInterceptor' "This object has already been built"

Tags: spring, spring-security, autowired, spring-boot

I want to implement method security.

I'm facing a problem with @Secured and @PreAuth annotations. Whenever I add any of those to my service interface, I receive an exception like the following. Without them, my app runs just fine.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodSecurityInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.methodSecurityInterceptor() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built
```

It's a REST services application.

Here are some relevant parts of my config. Please let me know if I should add anything else.

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {
...

    @Autowired
    private DatabaseAuthenticationProvider databaseAuthenticationProvider;
...
    @Configuration
    @Order(1)                                                        
    public static class RestWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
...
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
...
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/usuario/*/rfc/*").authenticated()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/usuario/*/rfc/*/").authenticated()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/usuario/*").authenticated()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/usuario/*/").authenticated()
...          
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return new AuthenticationManagerBuilder(new NopPostProcessor()).authenticationProvider(databaseAuthenticationProvider).build();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private static class NopPostProcessor implements ObjectPostProcessor {
        @Override
        public Object postProcess(Object object) {
            return object;
        }
    };

    @Bean
    public MessageDigestPasswordEncoder messageDigestPasswordEncoder() {
        return new MessageDigestPasswordEncoder("sha-256");
    }
}
```

And:

```
@Service("databaseAuthenticationProvider")
public class DatabaseAuthenticationProvider
    extends AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Autowired
    private MessageDigestPasswordEncoder messageDigestPasswordEncoder;
...
    @Override
    protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails arg0,
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken arg1)
        throws AuthenticationException {
        return;
    }
    @Override
    protected UserDetails retrieveUser(String username,
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication)
        throws AuthenticationException {
//        logger.debug("Inside retrieveUser");
        String password = (String) authentication.getCredentials();

        String encryptedPassword = "";

        if (StringUtils.hasText(password)) {
            encryptedPassword = messageDigestPasswordEncoder.encodePassword(password, null);
        }

        //UserDetails user = null;
        String expectedPassword = null;
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        WebAuthenticationDetails wad = null;
        wad = (WebAuthenticationDetails) authentication.getDetails();
...
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
            username,
            password, 
            true, // enabled 
            true, // account not expired
            true, // credentials not expired 
            true, // account not locked
            authorities);
    }
...
}
```

According to [AlreadyBuiltException documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/AlreadyBuiltException.html):

> Thrown when AbstractSecurityBuilder.build() is two or more times.

But I can't find out why spring is doing that.

Any ponters would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you all.

Here I put some more CallStack

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'usuarioServiceImpl' defined in file [C:\Users\ely\Documents\Desarrollo\Spring\workspace-sts-3.5.1.RELEASE\ws-timbrado-backend\target\classes\mx\i4b\timbrado\service\entidades\UsuarioServiceImpl.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodSecurityInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.methodSecurityInterceptor() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    ... 73 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodSecurityInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.methodSecurityInterceptor() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:597) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:989) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor.getAdvice(MethodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor.java:96) ~[spring-security-core-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJProxyUtils.isAspectJAdvice(AspectJProxyUtils.java:67) ~[spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJProxyUtils.makeAdvisorChainAspectJCapableIfNecessary(AspectJProxyUtils.java:49) ~[spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.extendAdvisors(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:97) ~[spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:89) ~[spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:69) ~[spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:376) ~[spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:339) ~[spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:421) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1558) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    ... 82 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.methodSecurityInterceptor() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:188) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:586) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    ... 101 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:42) ~[spring-security-config-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration.java:78) ~[spring-security-config-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.authenticationManager(GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.java:248) ~[spring-security-config-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.methodSecurityInterceptor(GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.java:119) ~[spring-security-config-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d8bcec4.CGLIB$methodSecurityInterceptor$8(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d8bcec4$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$42ba89ef.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312) ~[spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d8bcec4.methodSecurityInterceptor(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    ... 102 common frames omitted
```

---

*//////  **Update 1**  //////*

Based on @M.Dainum I removed my `authenticationManager`.

Tried to define my `databaseAuthenticationProvider` in three ways (included in this post), but all resulted in the same NullPointerException upon authentication.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:147) ~[spring-security-core-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
```

ProviderManager.java:147:

> ```
>         if (!provider.supports(toTest)) {
> ```

<del>- I don't think `provider` is null since I made sure my autowired `databaseAuthenticationProvider` wasn't. 

- `toTest` comes from `authentication.getClass()`. It shouldn't be null. Right? (Not sure if I remotely understood the problem)</del>

`getProviders()` contins:

> [null, org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider@490adcdf]

Made a mistake before: The provider is null. So the "Autowiriring" is not happenning.

I think this is because in order to use something like: `auth.authenticationProvider(databaseAuthenticationProvider);`, `databaseAuthenticationProvider` should be static and that prevents the autowiring. Right?

If I create it with "new", then afterwards the `messageDigestPasswordEncoder` is null, and so on.

So... How should I solve this?

Op1:

```
    @Configuration
    @Order(1)                                                        
    public static class RestWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationProvider(databaseAuthenticationProvider);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
```

Op2:

```
    @Configuration
    @Order(1)                                                        
    public static class RestWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http.authenticationProvider(databaseAuthenticationProvider);
```

Op3:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(databaseAuthenticationProvider);
    }
```

---

*//////  **Update 2**  //////*

To "force" the "Autowiriring", tried to remove `@Autowire` from the attribute and add it to a setter method like this:

```
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    private static DatabaseAuthenticationProvider databaseAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    public void setDatabaseAuthenticationProvider(DatabaseAuthenticationProvider databaseAuthenticationProvider) {
        WebSecurityConfig.databaseAuthenticationProvider = databaseAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)                                                        
    public static class RestWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            if (databaseAuthenticationProvider == null) {
                System.out.println("************************************************* databaseAuthenticationProvider es null");
            } else {
                System.out.println("************************************************* databaseAuthenticationProvider NO ES NULL");
            }
            auth.authenticationProvider(databaseAuthenticationProvider);
        }
```

And now: back to squere one:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.methodSecurityInterceptor() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built

I guess the problem wasnt that I had my own `AuthenticationManager`
Somehwere else is being built twice.

How to find it?

By the way... it still has null value:

> ************************************************* databaseAuthenticationProvider es null

Comment: You shouldn't have to build your own `AuthenticationManager` nor call the `build` method. Simply create a `configure` method in your `RestWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter` and in that method simply call the `authenticationProvider` as you do now. That should be all that is needed. You also need to make sure that you don't load your configuration twice (by mistake for instance).

Comment: But I have my own databaseAuthenticationProvider. How should I configure it otherwise?

Comment: By just setting it with calling the `authenticationProvider` method on the supplied `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` as I also mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: You are injecting into the wrong class. Inject the `DatabaseAuthenticationProvider` into your `RestWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter` not in your `WebSecurityConfig`.

Comment: Duh... you are right. Always assumed the "inner" classes would see "outer" class attributes.

Comment: @M.Deinum Please add an answer containting your second comment so I can mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to thank M.Deinum. I finally got it working.

It is as simple as this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)                                                        
    public static class RestWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private  DatabaseAuthenticationProvider databaseAuthenticationProvider;

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationProvider(databaseAuthenticationProvider);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/usuario/*/rfc/*").authenticated()
...
```

Now my service method is accessible only by the specified role like this:

```
@Secured({Sec.R_ADMIN})
Usuario getUsuarioByEmisorAndIdUsuario(Emisor emisor, String idUsuario, boolean consultarRoles) throws AuthorizationException;
```

Being:

```
public class Sec {
    public static final String R_ADMIN = "ROLE_ADMIN";
```

Answer (score 2):

After several hours testing every option, it worked for me this way:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

  @Bean
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationProvider provider) {
      return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(provider));
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      // here your permissions
  }
}
```